How to capture scroll position in vue 3 and nuxt3
I am trying to change the color of a scrollbar at a certain position but using window.scrollY seems to trigger errors:
  const navBar = computed<NavigationBarData>(
() => {
  if (window.scrollY < 100) {
    return {
      secondaryNavColor: 'transparent',
      primaryNavColor: 'transparent',
    }
  } else {
    return {
      secondaryNavColor: 'gray-lighten-3',
      primaryNavColor: 'surface',
    }
  }
}

)
My error this generates is:
500
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scrollY')

Why can we not use window.scrollY in vue3/nuxt3?

The problem is Nuxt, not Vue. You should at least avoid running this code on server side. It should be conditional at some point. The problem is possibly in a way you chose. window.scrollY is not reactive and it doesn't make sense to use it directly in a computed, There should've been a composable that's responsible for providing reactive position value, and that's where a condition should be contained

The error you're getting is caused by server-side rendering in Nuxt, where The window object is not available on the server.
You could wrap your calculation in the onMounted lifecycle hook, to ensure your calculation is always done in the browser context.
Something like:
const scrollY = ref(0)

const updateScrollY = () => {
  scrollY.value = window.scrollY
}

const navBar = computed<NavigationBarData>(() => ({
  secondaryNavColor: scrollY.value < 100 ? 'transparent' : 'gray-lighten-3',
  primaryNavColor: scrollY.value < 100 ? 'transparent' : 'surface',
}))

onMounted(() => {
  updateScrollY()
  window.addEventListener('scroll', updateScrollY)
})

onUnmounted(() => window.removeEventListener('scroll', updateScrollY))

Hope it helps.
